# vecファイルが複数存在する際のカスケード生成

Tags: opencv

画像複数枚を同時にvecファイルにしようとするとエラーをはいたので
1枚ずつ複数の画像をcreatesamplesを用いてvecファイルを作成しました．

しかし最終的にカスケード分類器を生成するとき，複数のvecファイルを扱う場合
どのようにしたらいいのでしょうか？

vecファイルを１つに統合したり，同時入力などができるのでしょうか？
初心者なので教えていただきたいです．

#### 補足

現在MacBookでhomebrewを用いてOpenCV3を導入しています．
プログラムで正解画像のリストをテキストファイルで作成し，
createsamplesで一斉にvecファイルにしてしまおうと考えました．

ターミナルで

```sh
$ opencv_createsamples -info pos.txt -vec pos.vec -num 89 -w 24 -h 24
```

と入力したところ，(ファイル内の画像数は89)

```
Info file name: pos.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: pos.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 89
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 24
Height: 24
Create training samples from images collection...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 &&
```

rect.x < image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)
(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0)) in 
cvSetImageROI, file /Users/_____/Desktop/opencv-2.4-
2.9/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 3006

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception:
```

/Users/_____/Desktop/opencv-2.4-2.9/modules/core/src/array.cpp:3006: error: 
(-215) rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x < image->width && rect.y < 
image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + 
rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0) in function cvSetImageROI

画像いっぱいいっぱいに判別したいものが写っている画像を用いているためpos.txtには
名前　数量　画像のサイズ(始点から終点)というふうに記入しています．

```
1.jpg 1 0 64 64 0
2.jpg 1 0 64 64 0
3.jpg 1 0 64 64 0
4.jpg 1 0 64 64 0
5.jpg 1 0 64 64 0
```

何が原因でエラーが起きているのかがわかりませんが，
１つ１つならcreatesamplesが使えたため上記のように
複数のvecファイルを使う方法を伺いました．

よろしくお願いします．

Comment: [削除された前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/37246/19110)に引き続いた質問かと思いますが、前回と同じく、amumu0122 さんが直面している問題が再現できるように、（失敗していても）今までの作業手順等を本文に追記してくださいませんか？　それが[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)につながり、回答が集まりやすくなるのではないかと思います。